# Should I use "this" or "the"

Tags: determiners

I have received an email about one project and I want to ask for more details. Which sentence is correct and why?

Could you provide me more information about this project ?

Could you provide me more information about the project ?

Answer (score 3):

I would say either version is completely understandable as long as the "project" is some where referenced in the e-mail string. For example, if you are just replying to an e-mail and the previous message and subject line are still intact. One subtle difference would be if you included the name of the project in the request for information. "Could you provide me more information about this Black River Project." could connote a hint of skepticism that is not there if you wrote, "Could you provide me with more information about the Black River Project."

Answer (score 0):

The determiner 'the' is in reference to any, whereas 'this' refers to more more specific. Usually 'this' is used where an object is visible, whereas 'the' is a little more arbitrary.

Comment: No.  "The" is the definite article and will apply to one specific project.